# how to differentiate this equation (contains absolute and norm)

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization, partial-derivative

how can I differentiate the following wrt $\mathbf{d}_i$?

$\frac{|\mathbf{d}_i^T\mathbf{d}_j|}{\|\mathbf{d}_i\|_2\|\mathbf{d}_j\|_2}$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**
For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$\nabla_{x} |x^Ty|= \text{sign}(|x^Ty|)y,\qquad  \nabla_{x}\|x\|_2 = \dfrac{ x }{ \|x\|_2 }, $$
So $$\nabla_x \left(\dfrac{|x^Ty|}{\|x\|_2\|y\|_2}\right) = \dfrac{\|x\|_2\nabla_{x}|x^Ty|+|x^Ty|\nabla_{x}\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_2^2\|y\|_2}=\ldots $$

Comment: $sign(|x^Ty|)$ is that correct?

Comment: @user570593 yes, for $g(t)=|f(t)|$ we have $g'(t)=\text{sign}(f(t))f'(t)= \frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}f'(t)$ for $f(t)\neq 0$